# autowiring spring bean in camel processor

Tags: spring, apache-camel, osgi, jbossfuse, blueprint-osgi

I am building OSGI bundle for running in Jboss Fuse 6.1 container. Project contains blueprint.xml (in src/main/resoureces/OSGI-INF/blueprint). It is content:

```
 <blueprint xmlns="http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0"
               xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
               xmlns:camel="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint"
               xmlns:camelcxf="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf"
               xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core"
               xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws"

               xsi:schemaLocation="
           http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0 http://www.osgi.org/xmlns/blueprint/v1.0.0/blueprint.xsd
             http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/cxf/camel-cxf.xsd
           http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint/camel-blueprint.xsd
            http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/jaxws http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/jaxws.xsd
     http://cxf.apache.org/blueprint/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/blueprint/core.xsd"
    >
<bean id="MyProcessor" class="com.test.MyProcessor" />
          <camelContext trace="false" id="blueprintContext" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/blueprint">
            <route>
                <from uri="activemq:queue:paymentsqueue?username=admin&amp;password=admin" id="NotificationRoute">
                    <description/>
                </from>
                <log message="The message contains ${body}"/>
                <process ref="MyProcessor"/>
            </route>
        </camelContext>
    </blueprint>
```

My goal is using spring beans in MyProcessor. This is code for MyProcessor:

```
public class MyProcessor implements Processor {

@Aurowired
private Sender sender;

@Override
public void process(Exchange x) throws Exception {
    log.info("test: " +sender.getSenderId());
}
```

}

But it gives me nullpointerexception. What I am doing wrong?

This is content of my spring configuration file(i placed it in src/main/resoureces/META-INF/spring)

```
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
   xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
   xmlns:context="http://www.springframework.org/schema/context"
   xmlns:p="http://www.springframework.org/schema/p"
   xmlns:aop="http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop"
   xmlns:tx="http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx"
   xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop http://www.springframework.org/schema/aop/spring-aop-3.1.xsd
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx http://www.springframework.org/schema/tx/spring-tx-3.1.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/context http://www.springframework.org/schema/context/spring-context-3.1.xsd">
    <context:annotation-config/>
    <context:component-scan base-package="com.username"/>
<bean id="sender" class="com.username.Sender" scope="prototype">
     <property name="senderId" value="sendername" />
     <property name="password" value="senderpassword" />
</bean>
```

Comment: Generally is it possible to use spring beans in blueprint beans   
simultaneously? As in my example where camel route and processor created by blueprint, but autowiring bean created by spring.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have not declared the Processor MyProcessor as a bean in spring like

```
<bean id="myProcessor"
        class="com.test.MyProcessor" />
```

then you can use it as

```
<process ref="myProcessor"/>
```

Also the

```
@Aurowired
private Sender sender;
```

should be @Autowired(This should be a typo but pointed it out.)

Comment: Yeah, I made a mistake when copied code above. This bean declared in blueprint. I have editted.